# Estimation of convergence speed

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $f(1)=f(2)=1$, for $n \geq 3$, $f(n)=\sum_{k= \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} f(k)$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
f(2m+1)=\sum_{k=m+1}^{2m} \frac{1}{k} f(k), \ f(2m+2)=\sum_{k=m+1}^{2m+1} \frac{1}{k} f(k), \ m\geq1.
\end{equation}
Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} nf(n)=\frac{1}{2 \log2-1}$. This result seems amazing and I believe its true, but I just don't know how to deal with this sequence.

Comment: What's the source of this problem ?

Comment: It comes from an exercise of probability, where $f(n)$ represents the probability distribution of some hitting time, the iterative formula is deduced from Law of Total Probability.